# How to get "edge" of non rectangular rotated UIImage?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I have an UIImageView with a png image inside. The ImageView is rotatable (by RotationRecognizer and UIImageView.transform).

[image: pic: image with frame]

Now I want to detect, whether the (i.e.) left image edge is outside it's superview – but of course only the non transparent content!
I tried to mask the image by

```
let maskLayer = CALayer()
maskLayer.contents = image.cgImage
maskLayer.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: image.size)
self.layer.mask = maskLayer
```

The mask works to only see the desired content but it has no effect to the "frame" for detecting the image's edge. I didn't find any "mask based" detection and hope, you can help me.

[image: pic: image without frame]

Comment: how you are rotating image, can you provide the code for it?

Comment: Yes, inside the UIRotationRecognizer method it's:

`if(sender.state == .began || sender.state == .changed){

            self.transform = self.transform.rotated(by: sender.rotation)
            sender.rotation = 0
        }` and self is the UIImageView.

Comment: frame do changing as you are rotating the view, but as you might be knowing the frame is respect to its superview, you can not check only for left edge. because after rotation your right edge may become the left edge and will be considered in the frame.

Comment: Yes I know. But I want to detect whether the visible (non transparent) part of the UIImage is outside the superview ... or when it is completely inside.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is use an external tool to create a convex hull that just covers the image. Then you rotate and position that convex hull exactly the same as your image. If any of the points lie outside the screen rectangle then your mask is also outside the screen.

How many vertices in the convex hull to convert your image mask to is up to you how accurate you want the test to be.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull